# Laravel - Extract only time from created_at using DB Raw

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this Query:

```
    $qualifiers = DB::table('vw_game_qualifiers as g')
    ->select(
       'g.msisdn', 
       'g.game_code',
       'g.user_channel',
       DB::raw("DATE(created_at) as created_date")
  )
```

I used

> DB::raw("DATE(created_at) as created_date")

to extract only date without time.

How do I extract only time (for example, 11:45:AM) without Date using DB Raw

Comment: Have you tried using TIME()?

Comment: Please use Eloquent model instead of query builder and cast the created at column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in views,Using Carbon you can do it,

```
{{Carbon\Carbon::parse($model->created_at)->format('H:i:s A')}}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
DB::raw('TIME(created_at) AS created_date')
```

Otherwise you can use this

```
$model->created_at->format('H:i:s');
```

Comment: How do I make it to display AM and PM  for eample  11:07:00 PM